# Getting oserror while reading file failed to load external entity

Tags: python

I am trying to identify the difference between two XML files using XMLDiff -> Diff_Files attribute. I am getting below error:

oserror error reading file "File1.xml" failed to load external entity "File2.xml"

Below is my code:

```
def FileCompare (golden_path,golden_File,Output_path,Output_File):

    try:
        gold_file=golden_File
        Out_file = Output_File
        gold_path=golden_path +"\\"+golden_File 
        Out_path =Output_path +"\\"+Output_File

        print('Files being compared', gold_file, Out_file)
        result = main.diff_files(gold_file, Out_file, 
                                         formatter=formatting.XMLFormatter())
        print (result)

    except:
        print(traceback.format_exc())
        pass
```

I checked the permissions on the file, but has full access. So not sure why it is giving me this error.

Comment: It might come from your XML encoding, or special characters inside  
Can you show samples ?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to stackoverflow.

According to the error message, File1.xml includes a file File2.xml and that cannot be read. So File2.xml it is either missing or on the worng relative position or is the file you are File1.xml comparing to and therefore already locked etc.

Comment: Ok So I put the files under same path from where I am running the code and now I am not seeing the error but instead its not comparing the file either. Now its simply parsing the file and returning me as a result and not the difference.

Comment: Files being compared File1.xml File1.xml
<ClinicalDocument><code code="55182-0" codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.6.1" codeSystemName="LOINC" displayName="Quality Measure Report"/><title>XYZZZ</title><effectiveTime value="20190717153758"/><confidentialityCode code="N" codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.5.25"/><languageCode code="en"/><recordTarget><patientRole><addr use="HP"><streetAddressLine>1</streetAddressLine><streetAddressLine>1</streetAddressLine></addr><telecom use="WP" value="tel:+1-123-456-7890"/></patientRole></recordTarget>
</ClinicalDocument>

Comment: I am receiving above result ..The purpose of the compare functionality: 1) Select two different folders which contains files with same name. So my folder 1 has lets say "File1, File2" and my folder 2 has "File1, File2". Now I am iterating through list of files, and pick the files with the same name from both the folder one by one and then simply compare them. So File 1 -> Folder 1 with File1 -> Folder 2 will be compared. In my above example, Both File1 has some difference in hence it should list the diff:Insert or whatever. But its instead printing the parsed file from Folder 1, File 1.